# how to reuse tableviewCell with autoLayout in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitableview

I have a tableview cell with an imageview and a button inside it. I add constraints for imageview and button. The tableview appears and the cell is displayed correctly. But when reuse the cell, I scroll down the tableView and scroll back up, cells are displayed wrong?

When I reuse the cell I add new constraints, there are conflicts with earlier constraints，I try to delete earlier constraints before adding new constraints but it does not work. Here is the project link:

https://github.com/chengyanan/chat

console throw warnings in case of autolayout errors:

```
2015-12-10 16:34:30.299 Chat[5488:133086] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7cc5b120 H:[UIImageView:0x7c94daa0(30)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7cc5a640 H:|-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7c94daa0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7c96bdb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ccab9e0 UIImageView:0x7c94daa0.right == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7c96bdb0.right - 8>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7cc71dc0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7c96bdb0(320)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ccab9e0 UIImageView:0x7c94daa0.right == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7c96bdb0.right - 8>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-12-10 16:34:30.300 Chat[5488:133086] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7cc5b120 H:[UIImageView:0x7c94daa0(30)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7cc59d40 H:[UIImageView:0x7c94daa0]-(3)-[UIButton:0x7c95b8b0'Trgghhh hhhhhhhhhhhbbbbbv...'](LTR)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7cc78640 H:[UIButton:0x7c95b8b0'Trgghhh hhhhhhhhhhhbbbbbv...'(255)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ccc99f0 UIButton:0x7c95b8b0'Trgghhh hhhhhhhhhhhbbbbbv...'.right == UIImageView:0x7c94daa0.left - 3>"
)
```

[image]

Comment: This could help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/452584

Comment: why dont u create 2 different cell for reply/answer with storyboard instead of creating it in code and add constraint by code, the bubble can be easily create by code instead of use uiimage too...

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to always remove and add new constraints? could you perhaps modify the current constraints in a UITableViewCell method during cellForRowAtIndexPath and it will layout correctly.